# How to embed a Youtube video in My website using a popup window? No Flash, No JS

Tags: html, video, youtube, popup

I need help writing code for my site that will enable me to create a video popup of a youtube video on my website. I would like to use html5 not flash or JS. That being said I can't seem to find any code samples to digest. I will keep looking but if you have any ideas to

1. create a html 5 popup for a youtube video
2. not using JS or Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a :target event with CSS to show a popup container.

Working Example:
http://jsbin.com/csspopupyoutube/2